# Absence of "and" between two relative pronoun clauses

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

> When you are anxious, the perceived threat potential of stimuli related to your anxiety can rise. **Thus, things you typically encounter that might not usually trigger fear now do so.**

I find the bold part weird. The grammar structure seems to be *(that) you typically encounter* and *that might not usually trigger fear now* modifying *things* as relative clauses.

Don't you need *and* between two clauses? Could anyone tell me how it is possible to omit "and" there? (in grammar).

Comment: I think you've read it wrong.  "that might not usually trigger . . . "--in this phrase "that" is a restrictive relative pronoun limiting "things (that) you typically encounter".

Comment: It's okay as it is. The relativised element is subject of the embedded "might not ... " clause, not object of "encounter". We understand that you typically encounter things that might not usually trigger fear.

Comment: well, "you typically encouter" is a restrictive relative pronoun clause modifying "things". Also, "that might not usually trigger fear" is also a restrictive relative pronoun clause modifying "things" too. My question is, when there are two restrictive relative pronoun clauses modifying a same noun, "things", why there is no "and" between these two clauses. Shouldn't it be, "things (that) you typically encounter and that might not usually trigger fear now do so." thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: There should not be "and". You're analysing it incorrectly. There is only one relative clause which is _that might not usually trigger fear_.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. If the "you typically encounter" is not a restrictive relative clause, what is it called in grammar? Is the sentence with an inversion, having an object in the front?